# Regex: How to remove empty spaces or newline character from html tags?

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have this kind of html tag, which is interrupted by space at some point after word `masuri:`

```
<p class="mb-40px">Aceasta este o melodie alcatuita din patru masuri:
reluata apoi de catre instrumentul solist cu un cintec popular.</p>
```

THE OUTPUT:

```
<p class="mb-40px">Aceasta este o melodie alcatuita din patru masuri: reluata apoi de catre instrumentul solist cu un cintec popular.</p>
```

I want to replace the newline character in that particular tag `<p class="mb-40px"></p>`

I find an old regex made by @Toto, seems good, but doesn't make the replacement in order to get the output:

FIND: `(?:<p class="mb-40px">|\G)(?:(?!</p>).)*?\s\K\s+`

REPLACE BY: `(leave empty)`

Comment: By space you mean newline character, right? You might also want to add a question to your statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply make the assumption based on your desired output that you want to replace a newline character instead of a space.

This will match any single occurence of a newline inside of the specified tag:

`(<p class="mb-40px">)+(.)+\K(\r\n|\r|\n)(?=.*<\/p>)`

##### Explanation:

`(<p class="mb-40px">)+(.)` matches the opening tag + any character that follows

`\K` resets the matches

`(\r\n|\r|\n)` matches the newline character

`(?=.*<\/p>)` checks for any character +

after the match

Comment: Your formula can be simplified as: `(REGION-START)+(.)+\K(FIND REGEX)(?=.*REGION-FINAL)`

Comment: thank you @mashuptwice

Comment: OR: `(REGION-START)+(.)+\K(FIND REGEX)(?s:(?=.*(REGION-FINAL)))`

Comment: @JustMe If your intention is to remove just a single newline even if there are multiple, `?s:` would work fine. If you would want to remove all newline characters instead use: `(<p class="mb-40px">)+(.)+\K(\r\n|\r|\n)+(?=.*<\/p>)`

Answer (score 0):

So, the regex that removes newsline is `(?<=[^\r\n])\R(?=[^\r\n])`. I put this regex in this new regex formula, at the end. See also below the source of how I manage to resolve the problem.

Use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find: `(?-i:<p class="mb-40px">|(?!\A)\G)(?s:(?!</p>).)*?\K(?-i:(?<=[^\r\n])\R(?=[^\r\n]))`
- Replace with: `\x20`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

---

I resolve this problem by reading [this topic:](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/20728/changing-data-inside-xml-element/15?_=1645999195443)

I fully endorse your new abbreviations ! So :

```
Let FR (Find Regex ) be the regex which defines the char, string or expression to be searched

Let RR (Replacement Regex ) be the regex which defines the char, string or expression which must replace the FR expression

Let BSR ( Begin Search-region Regex ) be the regex which defines the beginning of the area where the search for FR, must start

Let ESR ( End Search-region Regex) be the regex which defines, implicitly, the area where the search for FR, must end
```

Then, the generic regex can be expressed :

SEARCH: `(?-i:BSR|(?!\A)\G)(?s:(?!ESR).)*?\K(?-i:FR)`

REPLACE: `RR`

Comment: thank you @Rob Rob